# Angular 2 Data Table

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

The application is currently developed in Angular 2, and it needs jQuery datatable like table which have multiple features like sorting/pagination/fixed header/ column fixing/scrolling and others.

Lately I am not able to find any datatable plugin which is 100% compatible with Angular 2. Most closely compatible one in ngprime but that too shows script error with Angular2.

Techies/Hands-On-Folks out there can I get any recommendation/suggestion. Any blog/github author who has actually implemented it.

Comment: Try Kendo-grid for Angular

Comment: There is one in PrimeNG : https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable
Its super customization and lots of sample code available on their site.

Comment: @Indrajith it works well with Angular2 but has numerous issue with Angular 2. This error is very common below: If 'p-dataTable' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module. angular CLI

Comment: You have to import correct module for datatable. Angular cannot find the component declaration for p-dataTable. That's why its throwing an error. I have used PrimeNG datatable in multiple projects. No issue if used correctly.

Comment: @Indrajith agree to that cause I have limited knowledge as of now on Angular 2 so "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.0.0",  this is my current angular 2 which ngprime datamodel module you would recommend for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you have an error using the primeng datatable.
the steps are to correct install are :

1. Install the library

   ```
   npm install primeng --save
   ```

   your package.json should contain this dependency

   ```
   "dependencies": {
   ....
    "primeng": "^x.y.z",
    ....
    },
   ```
2. Change your app.module.ts and import your ngprime table

   ```
   import {GrowlModule} from 'primeng/primeng'
   @NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   FormsModule,
   HttpModule,
   GrowlModule
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried this as well it throws the below error:  If 'p-dataTable' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: To use `p-dataTable` you need to import `import {DataTableModule,SharedModule} from 'primeng/primeng';`. It's right there in the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable). `GrowlModule` is not needed for the data table at a basic level. That is why you are getting the error for this specifically.